# Editing "special recipes" Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

Despite the grindstone being added as the new way to combine items, mojang has marked that bug where players can still combine tools in the crafting grid as "wont fix".

So, obviously I have to fix it myself then through use of a datapack. However, I immediately noticed that they dont seem to have recipes like every other item in the game. I submitted a bug report and was told they are stored as a "special recipe".

According to the wiki, it should be stored as crafting_special_repairitem, but that is not showing up in the recipe generator I have been using, nor is it valid in game when I do /recipe give Aceplante crafting_special_repairitem.

I asked about this and was told: "That's the recipe type (with no further arguments, those are all build into the type), not the name." but I have no clue what that means.

How do I edit these special recipes such as tool combining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the file is simply called "repair_item", located in the recipes folder, so I'm not sure what the helper meant by special recipe.